# Is using autoFocus prop on input element bad when the input is conditinally rendered?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

this [eslint](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/f6ba03cd5c206e4ca04068253ab79ad32eb929ce/docs/rules/no-autofocus.md) says  Autofocusing elements can cause usability issues for sighted and non-sighted users, alike.

I am rendering the input element as a modal(i.e conditionally rendered) and as the modal is rendered I want the focus on input element.
The other approach is to do the same using `useRef` hook, But the point both autoFous prop and useRef have the same impact on a11y in my opinion(I am not sure hence asking).

The autoFocus is a easy way to focus as soon as the input is rendered and that's what I feel is best in terms of a11y when a modal is shown. The error might be applicable when autoFocus is done in the initial page load itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of the `autofocus` attribute is that it's primarily used when a page first loads. The accessibility concerns I've read (e.g., [Bruce Lawson's article on the `autofocus` attribute](https://brucelawson.co.uk/2009/the-accessibility-of-html-5-autofocus/)) are about `autofocus` dumping a user in the middle of a page when they'd normally use a screen reader to read a page from top to bottom, which can be distruptive for accessibility.

In my view, that doesn't apply to a modal, because a modal is designed to draw the user's attention to it. In fact, the [W3C WAI-ARIA Authoring Example of a modal](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html) dialog states that focus should be placed on the first focusable element (e.g., the input, the first paragraph, the OK button, etc.)

So, that's all to say, I think you should be fine from an accessibility standpoint to use `autofocus` on the `<input>` element in the modal when it first loads.