# Input field to accept text automatically without having to click on it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I am using a popup container in HTML, that contains one label (input) option for text, and a few buttons. I want the user to be able to start typing into the input field when the popup opens (which is triggered by a keyboard shortcut I am using), not necessarily having to click on it. how can i do so?

This is my HTML code snippet of the Popup menu:

```html
<div id="popupContainer">
  <div id="popupContent">
    <label for="AnnotateLabel">Label: <input type="text" id="AnnotateLabel" autocomplete="off" required></label><br>
    <button id="saveButton">Save</button>
    <button id="deleteButton">Delete</button><br><br>
    <!--<button id="closeButton">Close</button><br>-->
    <label for="loopRegion">Loop Region: <input type="checkbox" id="loopRegion" checked> </label><br>
    <!--<button id="playPopup">Play</button>-->
    <span>Playback Rate: </span>
    <button class="play-quarterx" data-action="play-quarterx">0.25x</button>
    <button class="play-halfx" data-action="play-halfx">0.5x</button>
    <button class="play-1x" data-action="play-1x">1.0x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the script which opens the menu do `document.querySelector('#AnnotateLabel').focus();`.

Comment: Depends on how you open the dialog / populate the dialog etc, but once the dialog is visible, use [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)

Comment: Thanks @Teemu , that worked. I wasn't calling the focus() method inside the popup code i wrote. Thank you so much!

Comment: [However](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71847289/is-using-autofocus-prop-on-input-element-bad-when-the-input-is-conditinally-rend)

Comment: It might be confusing for some that the linked duplicate answer is all about React, while this question is about native HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways.

### `autofocus` HTML attribute

HTML has support for this out of the box, without the need of JavaScript. You'll probably need to wrap your code in [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element, and then use [autofocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus) attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" id="AnnotateLabel" autocomplete="off" required autofocus>
```

### Use `HTMLElement.focus` method

JavaScript can also focus an element. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus). After showing the popup, make this call.

```js
document.getElementById('AnnotateLabel').focus();
```

Comment: Nice one. TIL autofocus. Available since end 2019 